# python update a list of dictionaries using another list of the same length

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to update a list `a` of dictionaries using another list `b` of the same length that each dict should add a key which corresponds to a value in `b` at the same position,

```
for x in range(len(a)):
    a[x]['val'] = b[x]
```

I am wondering is there a more efficient/concise way to do it

Comment: Pls provide sample input and desired output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could try using [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
for ai, bi in zip(a, b):
    ai["val"] = bi
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using python 3.x, you can use a list comprehension to create the new list on the fly:

```
a = [{'A': 1}, {'B': 2}]
b = [3,4]
[{**d, **{"val":b[i]}} for i, d in enumerate(a)]
```

Output:

```
[{'A': 1, 'val': 3}, {'B': 2, 'val': 4}]
```

Notice, though, that this doesn't apply on python 2.7. Another option would be to use a list comprehension to *update* each dictionary:

```
>>> a = [{'A': 1}, {'B': 2}]
>>> b = [3, 4]
>>> [x.update({"val":b[i]}) for i,x in enumerate(a)]
[None, None]
>>> a
[{'A': 1, 'val': 3}, {'B': 2, 'val': 4}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

dict = {'Name': 'Zara', 'Age': 7}
dict2 = {'Sex': 'female', 'Age': 17 }

dict.update(dict2)
```

[check here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_update.htm)